# Google Spreadsheets Conditional Formatting with color

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to add a column of cells together only if the particular cell is colored green. Can I do this using conditional formatting on a google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with a script (Extensions >> Apps Script) by using `getBackground()` in the [Spreadsheet Service of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range).

Answer (score 1):

No, Conditional formatting in Google Spreadsheets can only edit text and cell background color. You cannot use it to edit cell values. As [Brian P pointed out](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31786/29712) you can use scripts to do it.